# Bootstrap Multiselect not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, multi-select

I'm trying to use multiselect Bootstrap, I used the following code which is also available in their website too at (http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/), it shows the button for multi-select and as I already put the selected option for "cheese and pepperoni", it has already selected them too, but whenever I click on it, it does not open the list to choose!

```
<!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js'); ?>"></script>

<link href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
<link href="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">                  
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>    

<!-- Build your select: -->
<select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="my-select[]" id="my-select">
    <option value="cheese" selected>Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni" selected>Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {     
            $('.multiselect').multiselect();      
    });
</script>
```

Am I missing something?

Also if you think my question is not clear please let me know which part you need more clarification.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 16):

Try adding the bootstrap.js files (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). I missed those and it seems like these are required.

Comment: Perfect! Sometimes we miss the basics. I forgot to add this core bootstrap file and that's why it wasn't working. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just a note about a gotcha I encountered.  If for some reason the boostrap.js files are included _twice_ on your page (it can happen, therefore it did happen), the multi-select doesn't drop down.

Comment: It doesn't work for Bootstrap 5 in the latest version i have used it in Bootstrap 3 it works but not in bootstrap 5
any help
link 
https://jsfiddle.net/q8yd0Ljp/

Answer (score 2):

This Can solve your problem. Sometimes jsfiddle.net not working properly.

So please make one html file and copy below lines in it. It will work for you.

```html
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
           
        });
    </script>
    <select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple">
       <option value="cheese" selected>Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
        <option value="mushrooms" selected>Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni" selected>Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
    </select>  
</body>
```

Please share if you have any issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this: Add this where build your select is...
           <div class="input-group btn-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><b class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></b></span>
                <select id="example6" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
                <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
                <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
                <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
                <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
                <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
                <option value="onions">Onions</option>
                </select>

                <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected" style="width: auto;">None selected <b class="caret"></b></button>
                <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="cheese"> Cheese</label></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="tomatoes"> Tomatoes</label></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="mozarella"> Mozzarella</label></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms</label></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni</label></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="onions"> Onions</label></a></li></ul>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still it does not work; have you tried it on your computer or jsfiddle?

Comment: Your JSFIDDLE does not work either! Have you included everything?

Comment: hi, please go thru it, I have solved you problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/rajeshmpanchal/q3znu726/1/

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with the plugin and Internet Explorer, versions <= 10.

I have also managed to resolve this by adding the **DOCTYPE** tag at the beginning of my web page. This discovery was highly annoying, as IE sticks to XHTML.

Please verify that your web page begins with the following line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

On IE8 i was having issues. When i altered bootstarp-multiselect.js line  223

```
this.$select.wrap('<span class="hide-native-select">').after(this.$container);
```

to

```
this.$select.wrap('<span class="hide-native-select"></span>').after(this.$container);
```

and on line 1468

```
'class': option.class, to  'class': option['class'],
```

it worked

Answer (score 0):

check for any error in console . For me it was `" Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js"`.

```
<scriptsrc = https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.0.4/popper.js"></script>
```

adding this line after bootstrap.min.js issue was solved.