# Bootstrap Multiselect not allowing me to check list items that aren't already checked by default

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am trying to use [Bootstrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect). I am trying to use one of the examples. Here is that code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
       includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
</script> 

<select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="cheese" selected>Cheese</option>
   <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
   <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
   <option value="mushrooms" selected>Mushrooms</option>
   <option value="pepperoni" selected>Pepperoni</option>
   <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

It shows up on the page, and the options I hardcoded to be checked, are checked. But when I attempt to click other option's check boxes, to select them, the check boxes don't check (I hope that makes sense). It basically doesn't allow me to check anything that isn't checked by default.

I appears that someone else had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570027/bootstrap-multiselect-not-working). I'm hoping someone now may know the answer.

If any part of this isn't clear please comment.

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/vfy1tj5j/). It looks like it is working as is  expected. Please make sure you are not missing any js/css and that the multiselect js is included after bootstrap.js (just guessing)..

Comment: @Taleeb Yeah I have already checked that actually. I pulled in multiselect from bower, and it automatically placed it there.

Comment: Well... some clarifications then - Do you see any error in console? Are you using any other js library? Do you have some jquery code written for some other checkbox which may be conflicting here?

Comment: @Taleeb no errors in the console. I am using a lot of js libraries. I don't think any of them conflict with multiselect. I have not written any other jquery code.

Comment: I think then the last option is to debug the plugin code...

Answer (score 0):

here is the snippet it should work fine if you add following libraries.

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });

    });
</script>
<select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="cheese" selected>Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms" selected>Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni" selected>Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```