# Blazor Multi-Select does not make a dropdown

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

So, I have been trying out dropdown lists and found that those with checkboxes look nice thus I have been trying to implement it. And the result is that the thing looks alright. But I cannot seem to make the dropdown event to occur even after clicking on it. I used inspect element and I can see that the options exist. I followed [this](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) guide here. I tried using some of the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570027/bootstrap-multiselect-not-working) but none fixed the issue.

Supposed to look like:

[image]

What mine looks like

[image]
[image]

Here's the code

dropdownmenu.js

```
function GetMultiSelect(select) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(select).multiselect();
    })
}
```

DropDownTest.razor

```
@page "/dropdown"

@inject HttpClient _client
@inject IJSRuntime js
@attribute [Authorize]



<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>





@code {
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    }
    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("GetMultiSelect", "#example-getting-started");

    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>TestApp</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="TestApp.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="icon-512.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/datatable.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/dropdownmenu.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit 1:
Console does not show any errors when I am clicking the dropdown button.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `id` when you are initializing the multiselect : `$(document).ready(function () { $("#example-getting-started").multiselect();})`